# What is the error with these congruence equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Suppose I was trying to give some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $3x \equiv 5 \mod 7$ then multiplying by $12$ gives $36x \equiv 60 \mod 7 \implies x \equiv 4 \mod 7$ so we can easily deduce solutions from this.

Then my question is why exactly does this not work?

$3x \equiv 5 \mod 7$ then multiplying by $2$ gives $6x \equiv 10 \mod 7 \implies -x \equiv 10 \mod 7 \implies x \equiv -10 \mod 7 \implies x \equiv 3 \mod 7$

But obviously these solutions do not match?

Comment: how did you get $x\equiv 3\mod 7$ from $x\equiv -10 \mod 7$  ?

Comment: The only error is in the last implication. We have $x\equiv -10\pmod{7}\implies x\equiv -10+7\cdot 2\equiv 4\not\equiv 3\pmod{7}$.

Comment: ${\rm mod}\ 7\!:\,\ {-}10\equiv -10+7\equiv -3,\,$ not $\,3\ \ $

Comment: Oh I see it now thank you guys.